# re.search "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Tags: python, regex, datetime

In my dataframe "df" i have a column "Datetime" containing 500 rows. Each row contains a string object like the following : **2018-12-23T10:42:09.690Z**

It would be very helpful to have Date and Time separated in two different columns (Date and Time).

**Date**
2018-12-23

**Time**
10:42:09.69

I've tried following Code:

```
#Input:
string = df['Datetime']
#Date
regex_res = re.search(r'(([0-9]{4})[-]([0-9]{2})[-]([0-9]{2}))', string)
print(regex_res.group())

#Output:
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

It does work if i only use on specific string like "2018-12-23T10:42:09.690Z".

```
#Input:
test = "2018-12-23T10:42:09.690Z"
#Date
regex_res = re.search(r'(([0-9]{4})[-]([0-9]{2})[-]([0-9]{2}))', test)
print(regex_res.group())
#Output:
2018-12-23
```

Tests i've done:

Checking for Nulls. The Output gave me "False" for every row.

```
nan_rows = [df['Datetime'].isnull()]
```

Every row is of the type "class 'str'"

```
print (df['Datetime'].apply(type))
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Regards,

Elle

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Thanks for the link as well! Heaven! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract date and time into separate columns from the existing column you may use

```
df[['date', 'time']] = df['Datetime'].str.extract(r'\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d*)Z\b')
```

Or, to get rid of trailing zeros in the millisecond part:

```
 df[['date', 'time']] = df['Datetime'].str.extract(r'\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d*?)0*Z\b')
```

The regex is

```
\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d*?)0*Z\b
```

See [pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/fvzDle/1/)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary (remove if the datetime can be glued to word chars)
- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` - Group 1 (date): 4 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `-` and 2 digits
- `T` - a `T` letter
- `(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d*?)` - Group 2 (time): 2 digits, colon, repeated three times, then a `.` and any 0 or more digits but as few as possible
- `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
- `Z` - a `Z` letter
- `\b` - word boundary (remove if the datetime can be glued to word chars)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Thanks for the link as well! Heaven! :)